# Atmel Studio 7 command line build - define symbols on command line

Tags: atmelstudio

I am using the following command to build an atmel studio project on the command line:

`AtmelStudio.exe C:\blahblah\solution.atsln /rebuild DEBUG /project PROJNAME /out output.txt`

I would like to define symbols and override the values defined in the project's .cproj file, so that I do not need to define many different configurations. Is this possible, or do I need to use some other tool?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use "/projectconfig".
/projectconfig  Specifies the project configuration to build or deploy.
Must be used with /project